# Why did I receive downvotes on my Stack Overflow questions after I posted a question on Meta?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I just got four sequential down votes on [my Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1300056/rta). I had asked them a long before, so I am just surprised.

I know anybody can vote down at any time, but just an hour ago, I created an account on Meta Stack Overflow with the same myOpenID account and got seven down votes for a question.

Are those downvotes on Stack Overflow related to my question on Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: you dont have profile on stackoverflow yet

Comment: @Lucifer http://stackoverflow.com/users/1300056/rta

Comment: If you shared a link you your question on Meta, they'll get more attention and possibly more votes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It could possibly be related, but no one can say for certain. Downvoting is anonymous by design.

The thing is, when you post a series of bad or low-quality questions on one site, that's a sign to experienced users that you've probably posted bad questions on *other* sites. People often go and look at your recent questions, and if they find that their theory is correct, they'll downvote. On the other hand, if their theory is *incorrect* and you've actually asked good questions, you can benefit from this behavior as they'll generally *upvote* your questions or even answer them!

Ironically, asking this question calls *even more* attention to your questions and increases the chances people will look at them. Users who read your question here will wonder if those downvotes are legitimate, and check out your recent questions for themselves.

The same rules still apply, though, no matter how old the questions are. Good questions get upvotes; bad (or poorly-asked) questions get downvotes. If you're worried about the votes you're receiving on old questions, that might be a sign you should revisit those questions to edit and improve them.

If the downvotes are truly malicious (e.g., someone is out to get you), we have a script that runs automatically about every day to reverse these votes. You'll find more information [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Comment: +1 - I didn't do this for this user but I often am motivated to look into main account activity by bad content on meta

Comment: As i think reputation is very hard to earn in the basic principal of stackoverflow, so how it is very easy for some one to drop someone's reputation. sometime it could demoralize.

Comment: @RTA I know it can be upsetting to receive downvotes, but please do not take them personally. They just show that *something* is wrong with your question, and maybe take that as an incentive to think before you post a new one. Is that question on-topic? Have you done enough research? Is there any important information missing? Is your post properly formatted?

Comment: @RTA, reputation really isn't **that** hard to earn - 15 for an accepted answer, 10 for an answer upvote, 5 for a question upvote, 2 for accepting an answer, and 2 for having a suggested edit accepted. If you ask good questions, or post good answers, it's easy to gain rep. Downvotes cost far less rep than a single upvote provides, so if you're losing a lot of rep from downvotes, then you questions or answers must not be very good.